# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')

Tags: forms, typeerror

I have a application that goes from forms to discord, have not had any issues with it before and now it is giving me fits.

> const POST_URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1131262008973607053/p_96RKsDiGW47beGaVvsZhM7yMnKNbONv0d-6sYHHISEcZL0ym_0B1w7C7K-Bq_azsXV";

function onSubmit(e) {
const response = e.response.getItemResponses(); < it gets stuck on this line of code on response
let items = [];

Not really sure how to fix it so didn't want to touch it